# How can I connect two LANs with each Different DSL Lines?

Tags: networking, lan

How can I configure so that `OFFICE 1` can see `OFFICE 2` if I have an access point connecting the two offices.

- **OFFICE 1:** LAN A (192.168.2.1) with two DSL lines connected with a load balancer.
- **OFFICE 2:** LAN B (192.168.3.1) with one DSL line.

Features I need:

1. Allow users to Share Files
2. Allow users to Share Printers

I’m not good at networking but I was given this task.

Is it possible to connect them using the access point? Where should I connect the access point? To the Tplink Wireless router or direct to the 16-port switch?

I want them to have different DSL lines but can still see each other, I don’t want to connect all 3 DSL lines to the load balancer, or I need another load balancer?

[image: Connect Two LANs image]

Answer (score 1):

Having them on the same layer 2 network would not be advisable for a number of reasons, such as having presumably two DHCP servers on the same network, the possibility of routing internet traffic over the wireless bridge, unnecessary broadcast packets transversing the link, etc. You'll want change the subnet masks at both offices so they are on separate networks. You didnt specify what the models of the cisco switches are, so I'm unsure if they offer (or are configured to use) layer 3 switching. Assuming they're just layer 2 devices, you will want to plug the APs in to your TPLink routers, and ensure the appropriate routes are in place on the TPLinks so traffic to the different layer 3 networks will transverse the wireless bridge rather than the default route (which would be the DSL lines). I only have experience doing this with Cisco gear, but see the following link for how to configure your APs as wireless bridges. It is for a layer 2 bridge but it should be enough to get you started, just instead setup the APs in their own subnet. It would look like

192.168.2.1/24 Office 1 Network

192.168.3.1/24 Office 2 Network

192.168.4.1/24 Wireless Bridge Network

Right now it looks like you're using /16 subnets, so it shouldnt be a big deal to make these changes; just change the subnet mask.

https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/205142890-airMAX-Configure-a-Point-to-Point-Link-Layer-2-Transparent-Bridge-